# cannot implicitly convert type int to system collections generic list

Tags: c#

I've been knocking my head on the wall with this for too long. 
I'm making a blackjack game for school and I'm currently trying to get the card values and add them to their own list.

When I have it set as a var as you see commented out on top it works fine, but when I try to switch it to a list I get the aformentioned error. I'm sure it is something easy I am missing.

The error pops up at the end when I am trying to call the GetCardValue method.

Thanks for any insight.

```
        /*var cardValue = 0;
        foreach (Card card in userHand)
        {
            card.GetCardValue();
            cardValue = card.GetCardValue();
        }*/

        List<int> cardValue = new List<int>();
        foreach (Card card in userHand)
        {
            card.GetCardValue();
            cardValue = card.GetCardValue();
        }
```

Comment: _cardValue_ is a `List<int>` while GetCardValue return an int. Your commented out code works but the result is wrong. It returns the value of the last card in userHand

Comment: Are you intentionally calling `GetCardValue` twice?

Comment: hey Steve. I know the top code is wrong, I was just kind of showing my progress in how I am trying to work this out in my head. 

Rufus...that is a great question hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add, then `Add`:

```
    List<int> cardValue = new List<int>();

    foreach (Card card in userHand)
    {
        card.GetCardValue();

        // get Card Value and Add it to the list:
        cardValue.Add(card.GetCardValue()); // <- Add; not assign (=) 
    }
```

You can use *Linq* to make code shorter:

```
    List<int> cardValue = userHand
      .Select(card => card.GetCardValue())  
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks...error is gone. Now on to the next issue hahah.